# Mysql workbench system error : 0

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mysql-workbench

I'm working on `laravel` project (for the first time), And I want to use MySQL workbench for database. 
But when I set my settings

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 33060
user: homestead
pass: secret
```

I got this error:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet, system error: 0

What can I do?

Note : I'm using windows 10

**UPDATE #1 :** Mysql  workbench worked with these settings :
[image: Mysql workbench]

But I got an error when i tried to make (php artisan migrate)
[image: Php artisan migrate error]

This is a screen shot from my .env file:

[image: .env file]

Comment: try default mysql port 3306

Comment: @MikeFoxtech It didn't work

Comment: try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Phil Didn't work as well :(

Comment: @AdeebTwait From the mistake I see you continue to use port 33060 https://i.imgur.com/7n8v8N6.png . Try *php artisan cache:clear*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the problem by doing `vagrant up` and using the port 3306

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong port. 33060 is the default port for the new X protocol. MySQL Workbench however only uses the classic protocol atm.

Comment: 3306 is the MySQL standard port, as mentioned above. If that doesn't work either, update your question and tell us what exact error you get? Also check if the server is actually running on that port.

Comment: @MikeFoxtech I've updated my question, take a look :)

Comment: You should separate the questions. One is the Workbench problem, which seems to be solved now. The other one is about Laravel and PHP. Focus on a single aspect in each question to make it useful for other users too. Open a new question for your Laravel problem-

Comment: I solved the Workbench problem by using the settings shown in the picture above, And I solved the laravel problem by using `vagrant up`